# Extracting filename only with pattern matching

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

Is it possible to use `string.match` and return a capture until the last `.` character to stop at the extension part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
local str = "filename.lua.txt"
local cap = str:match("(.+)%..+")
print(cap)
```

Output: `filename.lua`

The key in this pattern is the greediness of `+` and to use `%.` to represent the literal `.`

Comment: Isn't more correct to use `+` instead of `*` since both parts can't be empty?

Comment: @user2779657 Sounds right. I didn't use `+` because I'm not sure both parts can't be empty in all the OS.

Comment: either part can be empty on **any** current OS. File names like `.foo` or `bar` are allowed on all systems.

Comment: @dualed At least WindowsXP doesn't allow file name like `.foo`

Comment: It does. You just can't create it through explorer, which adds numerous fun events when you have a file that already has a name like this.

Comment: @dualed It still doesn't matter. Because the OP raises the discussion that both parts can't be empty, so that's the solution he is seeking. If it's not true in his original problem, I'm sure he knows how to deal with it now.

Comment: I just provided feedback to your comment, as you wrote that you were still not sure *after* the OP has given their comment. No reason to lash out.

Comment: @dualed I get it, and thanks for the information :). Just trying to explain why I didn't change the answer back to using `*` after seeing your comment.